# Stuck after login

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 with the official upgrade tool. Everything worked fine, until i rebooted. I type in my password, my wallpaper and cursor is shown, but nothing happens (it's stuck).

Then i reinstalled my system from scratch. Everything worked fine, a couple of hours and reboots later, it's broken again, the same way.

Tried

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

, but i get these warnings/errors:

```
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0

(unity-tweak-tool:3487): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

Also tried the suggestion from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). After running ccsm, i get this output:

```
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 94, in <module>
    import ccm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ccm.Conflicts import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ccm.Constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Constants.py", line 30, in <module>
    CurrentScreenNum = gtk.gdk.display_get_default().get_default_screen().get_number()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'
```

Don't know if it's relevant, i'm using the proprietary NVidia driver (version 331.79), and i have 2 monitors.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so i upgraded my GTX 570 to a GTX 970, thought i would try again to see whether things have changed or not (installed driver 343.22).

Everything worked fine, a couple boots later at the login screen i can't type in my password, because my keyboard and mouse do not seem to work. After 5-10 secs on the login scrren, it simply freezes (have to press the reset button). It must be related to the original problem, because ~1 out of 3 boots i also end up with a low resolution.

Comment: Does the same happen if you disable and unplug the second monitor?

Comment: Yes. I unplugged my second monitor, it's still stuck. Also, i get the same errors this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to open terminal then type:

```
export DISPLAY=:0    
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/    
unity --reset-icons
```

This worked for me.